# Bing New Tab Page on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs, bing

For a long while, my computer had the default new tab page, which I liked. Recently, it has turned into a bing search bar tab. I hate bing. I checked all my settings, removed unused extensions, checked my Chrome files briefly, but I can't find how it keeps coming back!

At first I thought it was easy to find; it was set as the new tab page, but it isn't now and it's still here! I installed a new extension after a few tries trying to remove it, called "X New Page Tab", and it worked for one night, then Bing overrode it.

Any help please? I **really** don't want Bing as anything on my computer.

Comment: Have you tried `Open the New Tab Page` in `On Startup` under `chrome://settings/` ?

Comment: Yep, no luck there, still bing.

Comment: Only other thing I could suggest is changing `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet]
"EnableActiveProbing"=dword:00000000`

Comment: Okay, where do I add this to? It might work...

Comment: `win` +  `R`  > `regedit` > navigate to the above > edit EnableActiveProbing to dword:00000000 or create it if it doesn't exist

Comment: No luck still... God damn!

Answer (score 3):

I'm at work so I can't try this yet, but I saw this response on another site:

"if you can't remove Bing from Chrome, please see if you have installed a software called SEARCH PROTECT (CONDUIT).
It freezes your Browser setting and does not let you choose the settings that in my case made the browser stay always in Bing

Remove this profoundly and your browser will be OK"

Comment: WAIT! That's what it says at the top left of the window! Conduit! How do I remove it/find it? It isn't in my extensions or anything...

Answer (score 1):

1. Select: Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features
2. Scroll down to Search Project
3. Select Search Project
4. Right click and select uninstall

Answer (score 0):

I used the advice from above, but instead of uninstalling search protect altogether, use the option to select your preferred search settings.  All you have to do is click `Keep Search Protect installed`, then click on `Google`, and then `Apply Settings`.

Bing is gone and you still get the benefits of Search Protect.